# Moving Row Contents to Next Open Row in Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have two Sheets that I will be moving Data between frequently. On Sheet1, I have all my data and checkboxes are used to send that same data to Sheet2. When the data is sent over, empty rows are left behind so I know what positions are available when I rebuild the sheet at the end of the day.

The data on Sheet2 will be modified and at the end of the day I'd like to move everything back to Sheet1 taking the first available empty row. I have the first part working fine, but I cannot seem to get the data to move back to Sheet1 into the first available (empty Cell).

Currently the issue is when I uncheck the box to give the row a value of false, the data is removed from Sheet2 but not moved into Sheet1.

Here is what I have so far:

```
function onEdit(event) {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var s = event.source.getActiveSheet();
var r = event.source.getActiveRange();

if(s.getName() == "Foss Test 2" && r.getColumn() == 4 && r.getValue() == true) {
var row = r.getRow();
var numColumns = s.getLastColumn();
var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Foss Test");
var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
s.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns).moveTo(target);
} else if(s.getName() == "Foss Test" && r.getColumn() == 4 && r.getValue() == false) {
var row = r.getRow();
var numColumns = s.getLastColumn();
var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Foss Test 2");
var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getDataRange().getHeight() + 1, 1)
targetSheet.appendRow(target.getValues()[0]);
s.deleteRow(row);
}
}
```

I feel like my error is in the `else` block as currently no data is moved back to Sheet1.

Comment: source is undefined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although you didn't define the term "source" I assume this is what you want.

```
function onEdit(e) {
  e.source.toast('flag0');
  var sh=e.range.getSheet();
  if(sh.getName()=="Sheet1" && e.range.columnStart==4 && e.value=="TRUE") {
    var targetSheet=e.source.getSheetByName("Sheet2");
    var target=targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1,1);
    sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart,1,1,sh.getLastColumn()).moveTo(target);
  } else if(sh.getName()=="Sheet2" && e.range.columnStart==4 && e.value=="FALSE") {
    var targetSheet=e.source.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
    var vA=targetSheet.getDataRange().getValues();
    for(var i=0;i<vA.length;i++) {
      if(vA[i].join('').length==0) {
        var target=targetSheet.getRange(i+1,1);
        sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart,1,1,sh.getLastColumn()).moveTo(target);
        break;
      }
    }   
  }
}
```

If that's not what you want please let me know.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work quite right. Items don't move between sheets at all now.

I have gone back and changed "source" to "targetSheet" but that doesn't seem to work either.

Comment: I found a problem try it again.

Comment: Still doesn't seem to move anything. When I hit the checkbox to assign that row a value of TRUE or FALSE, nothing is moved.

I have updated my code in the post. When the checkbox is enabled (true), data is moved to Sheet 2. Now, when I uncheck the box (false), the data is removed from Sheet 2, but not added back to Sheet 1

Comment: Thank you that's closer, however when the data is added back to Sheet1, it's placed in the last row. I'd like for it to go to the first row that has no data.

Comment: I think that's it.

Comment: Here, [here is a copy](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/118Z5yN3Bn88EqRH4-mQyRI_hrVNfWoVXADvU_35KWB0/edit?usp=sharing) I made. You can see that Name 1 was moved back to Sheet1 in the 10th position, even with an available empty row (2)

Comment: Most recent update is perfect. I have a lot to learn, this was not where my mind was headed at all. Thank you, Cooper!

Comment: I just added a break so that the loop stops immediately after the move.